# Can't assign text to cell with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to scrape zip codes from Google. I've been trying to put `innertext` into a cell, but I think I may be getting a variable mismatch on 2nd to last line.

```
'This Must go at the top of your module. It's used to set IE as the active window

Sub Automate_IE_Enter_Data()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Dim adds As Variant, add As Variant
    Dim addt As String


    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://www.google.com/search?ei=djKhW7nELYqs8AO96baoAw&q=1000 Westover Rd kansas city, Mo"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertantly skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

    'Get Window ID for IE so we can set it as activate window
    HWNDSrc = IE.Hwnd
    'Set IE as Active Window
    'SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

    Debug.Print "ihgc"

    'Unload IE
endmacro:
    Set adds = IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("desktop-title-subcontent")

        For Each add In adds

            Debug.Print add.innertext
        Next

        Cells(2, f).Value = add.innertext
End Sub
```

Comment: Why have you typed "jvcghjokjhvcdf..." at the end of this?

Comment: What's with `Cells(2, f)`? Firstly, `f` is not defined anywhere in your code. Appears you would be wanting `Cells(2, "F")`. Next, you do understand that you are updating only 1 cell: 1.) this line isn't within your loop, 2.) even if it was, you are using the same cell address anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things. First and foremost, your loop is unnecessary. I ran your code, and there's nothing to loop. Even if it was necessary, it's being used improperly.

So, in assuming that you in fact do not need a `For...Next` loop, then you can use the **index** number of `0` for your collection of `IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("desktop-title-subcontent")`, then set your cell reference equal to the `innerText` property of that collection item.

This brings me to the next issue, your cell reference. `Cells(2, f)`, the `f` is not a declared variable. If you where actually wanting to use the column "F", then you need to enclose 'F' in double quotes:
`Cells(2, "F")` or use the column's index of `6`, `Cells(2, 6)`

So, replace this entire portion:

```
Set adds = IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("desktop-title-subcontent")

    For Each add In adds

        Debug.Print add.innertext
    Next

    Cells(2, f).Value = add.innertext
```

with this:

```
Cells(2, "F").Value = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName _
            ("desktop-title-subcontent")(0).innerText
```

---

### OPTIONAL

And lastly, I would look into using [Early Binding over late binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation). It has many advantages, with a possible notable speed improvement.

You would need to set a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls` and declare `IE` as type `InternetExplorer` vs `Object`. But that's not going to make or break your code.

Comment: thanks, i added a loop to proccess a column of addresses, but times out after 17?

Comment: I now get a problem when there is no address I tried this, but dd not work

Comment: can you help with next question

Comment: Sorry, the way StackOverflow works is that you can only ask one question per post. Unfortunately that means you will have to [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you want to post the link here to your new question then I will take a look at it when I have a chance (end of month is busy time for me at work, so someone else may be able to help before I get a chance). Thanks!